# How to make VS Code autocomplete a callable property to an arrow function instead of a regular function?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

When working with ts/tsx files, VS Code autocompletion for callable properties includes 2 options: `propertyName` and `propertyName(args)`:

[image: autocompletion options]

But using the second option produces a regular function:

[image: property with a regular function]

While I'd prefer an arrow function:

[image: property with an arrow function]

Is there any VS Code or Typescript setting that switches the autocompletion to arrow functions?

Comment: your second and third images should be code blocks and not images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, at the time of this writing, this is not supported by the builtin TypeScript Language Feature extension of VS Code. The only control that currently exists over the object literal method snippets feature you're talking about is whether to enable it or not (the `typescript.suggest.objectLiteralMethodSnippets.enabled` setting). There was talk about having such a user configuration point, but I don't think it went through to any kind of implementation (See [this comment in TypeScript issue ticket #46590](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46590#issuecomment-966550177) and the following comments). You could try to create a new issue ticket and ask that that discussion continue.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that there's at least an option to turn off method snippets. I'm not planning to open a ticket, considering that it was already raised without success in the ticket you mentioned above.